# Using knockout.simpleGrid.3.0.js with Require.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, requirejs

I am using require.js with knockout on a website and would like to use the simpleGrid example from this link http://knockoutjs.com/examples/grid.html however I cannot include kncokout.simpleGrid.3.0.js with Require.

I have tried wrapping the plugin with

```
define(['jQuery', 'knockout'], // Require knockout
    function($, ko) {

   });
```

This does not work it seems the problem occurs with the templates.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In your require config, you should create a path to the simpleGrid library and use the shim to tell it that it depends on Knockout so that your libraries are loaded in the correct order. Here's an example:

```
var require = {
    paths: {
        'jquery': 'lib/vendor/jquery-2.0.3',
        'ko': 'lib/vendor/knockout-3.0.0',
        'koSimpleGrid': 'lib/vendor/knockout.simpleGrid.3.0'
    },
    shim: {
        'koSimpleGrid': {
            deps: ['ko']
        },
    }
};
```

And then you could copy paste the view model code from the example inside of a define like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'ko', 'koSimpleGrid'], function ($, ko) {
    // VIEW MODEL GOES HERE
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree the problem seems to be with the code that writes the grid template.  Essentially, *because requirejs loads modules asynchronously*, `document.write()` can't be used - writing of the document *has finished* by the time a module executes. [This StackOverflow answer explains it well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24297863/998793) I think.

I got round it by instead **creating and appending the required script tag templates using dom methods**:

```
templateEngine.addTemplate = function(templateName, templateMarkup) {
  var scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type = 'text/html';
  scriptTag.id = templateName;
  scriptTag.text = templateMarkup;
  document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
};
```

[My amd version is in this gist](https://gist.github.com/rogersillito/1e2e6ba696b81c30f0471229814568aa).